# Preserve custom class name CKEditor5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I using a plugin to add a custom class to the mediaEmbed. Works fine, but when I reload the page the editor filter the class name. The class name is applied to the `<figure>` html tag. I tried to apply follow the example here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/conversion/conversion-preserving-custom-content.html#loading-content-with-all-attributes and while the class name is preserve the `<figure>` element is duplicated. Seem like there is not a simple solution of this.